# Why won't PHP recognize two equal strings?

Tags: php, arrays, comparison-operators

I'm working on a php function that will compare the components of two arrays. Each value in the arrays are only one english word long. No spaces. No characters.

> Array #1: a list of the most commonly used words in the english
>   language. $common_words_array
>
> Array #2: a user-generated sentence, converted to lowercase, stripped
>   of punctuation, and exploded() using the space (" ") as a delimiter.
>   $study_array
>
> There's also a $com_study array, which is used in this case to keep
>   track of the order of commonly used words which get replaced in the
>   $study_array by a "_" character.

Using nested for loops, what SHOULD happen is that the script should compare each value in Array #2 to each value in Array #1. When it finds a match (aka. a commonly used english word), it will do some other magic that's irrelevant to the current problem.

As of right now, PHP doesn't recognize when two array string values are equivalent. I'm adding in the code to the problematic function here for reference. I've added in a lot of unnecessary echo commands in order to localize the problem to the if statement.

Can anybody see something that I've missed? The same algorithm worked perfectly in Python.

```
function create_question($study_array, $com_study, $common_words_array)
{
for ($study=0; $study<count($study_array); $study++)
    {
    echo count($study_array)." total in study_array<br>";
    echo "study is ".$study."<br>";

    for ($common=0; $common<count($common_words_array); $common++)
        {
        echo count($common_words_array)." total in common_words_array<br>";
        echo "common is ".$common."<br>";

        echo "-----<br>";
        echo $study_array[$study]." is the study list word<br>";
        echo $common_words_array[$common]." is the common word<br>";
        echo "-----<br>";

          // The issue happens right here.
          if ($study_array[$study] == $common_words_array[$common])
            {
            array_push($com_study, $study_array[$study]);
            $study_array[$study] = "_";
            print_r($com_study);
            print_r($study_array);
            }
        }
    }

    $create_question_return_array = array();
    $create_question_return_array[0] = $study_array;
    $create_question_return_array[1] = $com_study;

    return $create_question_return_array;
}
```

EDIT: At the suggestion of you amazing coders, I've updated the if statement to be much more simple for purposes of debugging. See below. Still having the same issue of not activating the if statement.

```
if (strcmp($study_array[$study],$common_words_array[$common])==0)
{
echo "match found";
//array_push($com_study, $study_array[$study]);
//$study_array[$study] = "_";
//print_r($com_study);
//print_r($study_array);
}
```

EDIT: At bansi's request, here's the main interface snippet where I'm calling the function.

```
$testarray = array();

$string = "This is a string";
$testarray = create_study_string_array($string);

$testarray = create_question($testarray, $matching, $common_words_array);
```

As for the result, I'm just getting a blank screen. I would expect to have the simplified echo statement output "match found" to the screen, but that's not happening.

Comment: `$study_array[study]` should be `$study_array[$study]`

Comment: Well, that's embarrassing. Thanks for that. But even with that fix, I can't seem to get the code to print_r() the $com_study and $study_array. Any ideas?

Comment: can you show us the output and how you are calling the function (i mean the calling variables)?

Comment: Sure thing. Give me a sec to edit the question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(EDIT) make sure your that your splitting function removes excess whitespace (e.g. `preg_split("\\s+", $input)`) and that the input is normalized properly (lowercase'd, special chars stripped out, etc.).

Comment: Simply replacing the <br> tags with carriage returns made the if statement work for you?

Comment: @elersong sorry no, i didn't mean that--i only turned them to carriage returns because i was running this from console, not browser. i didn't make any other changes to your code and it detected "a" and "bear" as common words, which is why it would be helpful to see a set of inputs that don't work for you.

Comment: I updated the $common_words_array to hold the values ('this', 'is', 'a') and nothing else.

Comment: But then, I took it a step further and replaced the if statement with this:

Comment: if (strcmp($common_words_array[$common],"the")==0)

Comment: It would appear that there's something wrong with the $common_words_array, but I don't even know where to begin debugging that. I've never had a problem with a basic data structure before.

Comment: one last thing--make certain your splitting function doesn't leave any excess whitespace. also make sure the input string is being normalized as expected (e.g. all lowercase, special chars stripped, etc.)

Comment: WHOA! That did it! Thanks so much! If you will leave that as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted and close out this ticket.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
array_push($com_study, $study_array[study]);
```

to

```
array_push($com_study, $study_array[$study]);
 // You missed a $                  ^ here
```

**Edit:**
The following code outputs 3 'match found'. i don't know the values of `$common_words_array` and `$matching`, so i used some arbitrary values, also instead of using function `create_study_string_array` i just used explode. still confused, can't figure out what exactly you are trying to achieve.

```
<?php
$testarray = array ();

$string = "this is a string";
$testarray = explode ( ' ', $string );
$common_words_array = array (
        'is',
        'a',
        'this' 
);
$matching = array (
        'a',
        'and',
        'this' 
);

$testarray = create_question ( $testarray, $matching, $common_words_array );

function create_question($study_array, $com_study, $common_words_array) {
    echo count ( $study_array ) . " total in study_array<br>";
    echo count ( $common_words_array ) . " total in common_words_array<br>";
    for($study = 0; $study < count ( $study_array ); $study ++) {
        // echo "study is " . $study . "<br>";

        for($common = 0; $common < count ( $common_words_array ); $common ++) {
            // The issue happens right here.
            if (strcmp ( $study_array [$study], $common_words_array [$common] ) == 0) {
                echo "match found";
            }
        }
    }

    $create_question_return_array = array ();
    $create_question_return_array [0] = $study_array;
    $create_question_return_array [1] = $com_study;

    return $create_question_return_array;
}

?>
```

*Output:*

```
4 total in study_array
3 total in common_words_array
match foundmatch foundmatch found
```

Answer (score 1):

On mobile and can't seem to copy text. You forgot a dollar sign when accessing the study array in your push command.

Answer (score 0):

Use === instead of ==

```
if ($study_array[$study] === $common_words_array[$common])
```

OR even better use [strcmp](https://www.php.net/strcmp)

```
 if (strcmp($study_array[$study],$common_words_array[$common])==0)
```

Comment: I'm trying it now, but why exactly is that better than the if statement, semantically speaking?

Comment: == checks for equality, ===  checks if the values are equal and of the same variable type.

Comment: I made the changes to include the strcmp() function, but even still, I'm getting no luck. I really wish jsfiddle had a PHP option.

Answer (score 0):

Use built-in functions wherever possible to avoid unnecessary code and typos. Also, providing sample inputs would be helpful too.

```
$study_array = array("a", "cat", "sat", "on","the","mat");
$common_words_array = array('the','a');
$matching_words = array();

foreach($study_array as $study_word_index=>$study_word){

    if(in_array($study_word, $common_words_array)){

        $matching_words[] = $study_word;

        $study_array[$study_word_index] = "_";

        //do something with matching words
    }

}

print_r($study_array);

print_r($matching_words);
```

Comment: I tried this as well, but the line that should replace the common words with a "_" doesn't work. When I print_r() the $study_array, it looks identical to how it did before running the function. Any idea why?

Comment: I've altered the $common_words_array to include ('this', 'is', 'a') and nothing else. Still no matches are recognized.